# How to determine the latest OpenSSL version

Tags: ssl, nginx, openssl

What is the most reliable source to find the latest version number?
Is it [github](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/releases)?

And if yes, which version should I take?
Right now, here is what I see:
[image: github release page]

Should I take the `1.0.2k`?
But then `1.1.0d` seems like it is more recent (if it follows semantic versioning). What do the letters actually mean?

Note: in my case this is to compile an openssl version with nginx.
Last time I picked (quite randomly) the version 1.0.2h which seemed the latest at the time.

So what is the process to follow to find the latest openssl version?

Comment: See [The New Release Strategy](https://www.openssl.org/blog/blog/2014/12/23/the-new-release-strategy/) on the OenSSL blog and [Release Strategy Policies](https://www.openssl.org/policies/releasestrat.html) on the OpenSSL website.

Comment: @jww that's helpful, but I did not see the versioning explained there (as in, do they follow `1.0.2`, `1.0.2a`, `1.0.2b`...?).

Comment: See the OpenSSL man pages for `OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER`, [How does the versioning scheme work?](https://www.openssl.org/docs/faq.html#MISC8) from the OpenSSL FAQ or [OpenSSL binary distribution: meaning of the char at the end of version](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10347221/608639) on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @jww thanks, between your comments and Steffen answer, I understand now how this works.
I will stick to the LTS versions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://www.openssl.org/ shows which version are current and supported. 
Currently there are two major versions in development: 1.1.0 and 1.0.2. 1.1.0 is newer and has more features. But due to the cleanups between 1.0.2 and 1.1.0 lots of undocumented API (i.e. things which never were an official API but got used anyway since no official API existed) got broken and not all software works or works stable with 1.1.0 yet. Also, 1.1.0 tends to introduce not only features but also bugs faster than 1.0.2 when looking at the release history. And with 1.1.0 the chance is higher that [documented behavior changes](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/1903#issuecomment-260386036) even between patch releases.

Thus if you need the new features with 1.1.0 then go with it. If you prefer a more stable version with a smaller chance of bugs use 1.0.2. In all cases you should always use the latest patch release and keep using it if new patches get released or backport security patches.